# Python, def_init_(self): syntax error

Tags: python

New to python creating a function

```html
>> class students:
...  def_init_(self,name,age):
```

This leads to Invalid syntax  so I remove the ":" not sure why this happens in the video he receives no errors

```html
>> class students:
...  def_init_(self,name,age)
...  self.name=name
...  self.age= age
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in students
NameError: name 'def_init_' is not defined
```

From here I am uncertain how to advance, or what mistakes im making. I'd appreciate it if anyone could explain what I've done wrong.
      Thank you for taking the time out of your day to help.

Comment: Should be `__init__`. Two underscores for `init` and a space between `def` and `__init__`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.
Creating a class initialization function is documented quite well in a variety of places; how did *none* of those fix your problem?

Comment: Oh and also, add a space between`def` and `__init__`, like thiis:

    def __init__(self, name, age):

Comment: You have two problems. **(1)** You need to put a space between the `def` keyword and the name of the constructor `_init_`. **(2)** the constructor magic method named is `__init__` with double underscores, not `_init_`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
def_init_(self,name,age)
```

You should use

```
def __init__(self,name,age):
```

def means you start a function (definition), and it needs a space to follow.

The function __init__ is the constructor.

There should always be a colon at the end of a function definition (followed by the body of the function).

Answer (score 0):

You should have `def __init__(self, name, age):`

You need a space between `def` and `__init__`

Just a heads up intro questions like this are plentiful online.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem but when I separated the `def` from the `__init__` and placed two underscores in the `__init__` method as per Christian Dean, it worked!!!

```
class Person:
     def __init__(self, name, age):
            self.name = name
            self.age = age

person = Person("John", 36)

print(person.name)
print(person.age)
```